how do you set the title of a tab when using the 'dtale' module
Trying to set the title of the tab being displayed by dtale (d-tale)
Tried passing main_title='My title' as an argument to dtale.show but hat doesnt work

# after looking at dtale views.py came up with this workaround

import dtale
from dtale.global_state import get_app_settings, set_app_settings
import pandas as pd

def show_with_custom_title(df, title, name=None):
    # Set the main_title in the application settings
    settings = get_app_settings()
    settings['main_title'] = title
    set_app_settings(settings)
    
    # Display the DataFrame in D-Tale
    return dtale.show(df, name=name)

# Example usage
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
d = show_with_custom_title(df, "Your Custom Title", name="custom_dataset_name")

